# Getting the params in a url but not using question mark

Tags: php, url

Is there any code where I could insert a parameter in the url but not using question mark, "?"

For example:
http://website.com/GR/

In the given URL, it is supposed to direct you to the /GR folder. But there is no such /GR folder, instead, the GR is a parameter used by the base directory/url "website.com"

A base example is http://www.imgdaddy.com/11M/ and change the letter M up to Z.

Comment: You can achieve such behaviour using url rewrite defined in a .htaccess file. You can find additional info on this subject all over the internet. A nice introduction is for example here http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml. Once you try some code and you run into any problem, you should start a new question featuring the code you have tried so far. Note: not all webhosts support the using of .htaccess.

Answer (score 3):

In the `.htaccess` file,

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /?V=$1 [R]
```

would convert `http://site.com/GR/` into `http://site.com/?V=GR`

There isn't enough information in your question to be very specific because you don't say how the parameter should be used. [Apache provide more information](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: it sort of look like this. I tried this and it creates a ?V=GR at the end. But what I wanted was to make the URL still the same.

Comment: Don't use `[R]` at the end as that is what forces the explicit redirect. The options are explained at the link to Apache's documentation. For instance, you might want `NC` or `L` (or both, or some other combination).

Comment: Thanks, but the CSS and other image refer to the folder. For example site.com/tse/, the webpage is loaded from the site.com but all the css, images, and javascripts are linked to the /tse folder. I have tried NC, L, and R.

Comment: Put the external files in a static place, say `site.com/css/*.css` or `site.com/images/*.jpg` and then reference them with those urls (`/css/*.css` or `/images/*.jpg` with the initial backslash). But this is outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to achieve something like what a lot of PHP frameworks do, for example http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

The principle of operationg for such a solution is that you have a common controller class for every URI request made to your website. This is achieved in codeigniter by addresses such as `web.com/index.php/GR` as seen in the above link. You can use .htaccess rules to rewrite this so that the index.php part is omitted, however you get to have all the flexibility of having a nice friendly looking URI to share with no need for GET parameters.

Comment: the problem here is, the CSS is removed. What should I do?